# SSRS: Grouping a List report with a chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am trying to create a list type report and can't seem to get the groupings correct.  I am using VS 2017.

Here is the data set:

```
student_id  full_name   dob email   note    session_desc    Percentage
6   Test Student    2008-07-24  Sample email    Sample Note Main Session 1  59.5
6   Test Student    2008-07-24  Sample email    Sample Note Main Session 2  61.5
6   Test Student    2008-07-24  Sample email    Sample Note Main Session 3  66.9
6   Test Student    2008-07-24  Sample email    Sample Note Main Session 4  64.9
```

I am trying to get the report to look like this (I cannot embed images):

At the top I have a rectangle with the parent group:

```
                Test Student1
                DOB: 1/1/2000
                Email: test@gmail.com
```

And then inside another list or rectangle below, I want the detail records:

```
Main Session1   59.5%        Line chart here from 0-100
Main Session2   61.5%        Line chart here from 0-100
Main session3   66.9%        Line chart here from 0-100
Main Session4   64.9%        Line chart here from 0-100
```

This format would repeat for each student in the dataset.  I am trying to use lists, but everything I have tried repeats the Student,dob,email info for the detail records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with a larger version of your sample data so it included two students. Here's the dataset query I used to generate the data

**note** when I recorded the GIF I had the percentage column with the wrong number of decimals (`decimal(5,2)` instead of `decimal(5,3)`) hence why there are no decimals in the final output.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(student_id int, full_name varchar(50),  dob date, email varchar(100),   note varchar(100),    session_desc varchar(100), Percentage decimal(5,3))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(6, 'Test Student', '2008-07-24', 'Sample email', 'Sample Note', 'Main Session 1', 0.595), 
(6, 'Test Student', '2008-07-24', 'Sample email', 'Sample Note', 'Main Session 2', 0.615), 
(6, 'Test Student', '2008-07-24', 'Sample email', 'Sample Note', 'Main Session 3', 0.669), 
(6, 'Test Student', '2008-07-24', 'Sample email', 'Sample Note', 'Main Session 4', 0.649),
(7, 'Test Student 2', '2008-07-01', 'Another email', 'Another Note', 'Main Session 1', 0.495), 
(7, 'Test Student 2', '2008-07-01', 'Another email', 'Another Note', 'Main Session 2', 0.515), 
(7, 'Test Student 2', '2008-07-01', 'Another email', 'Another Note', 'Main Session 3', 0.569), 
(7, 'Test Student 2', '2008-07-01', 'Another email', 'Another Note', 'Main Session 4', 0.549)

SELECT * FROM @t
```

other than that I changed the percentages to be the correct decimal version (e.g. 0.5 = 50%), it's easier to work with and format in the report.

I didn't know what you meant by line chart so I added a databar to represent the percentage, I set the max value to 1 as our percentages are now all between 0 and 1

This clip starts after I added the dataset with the sample data and added a simple table. When you watch, the yellow highlights are left-clicks and the red highlights are right-clicks.

As you can seem even with a bit of clean up at the end the whole process take about 3 minutes to get the basic report running.

If you want to download the gif to watch it later or fullscreen, it's here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Fl2.gif

Hope this helps you in the future.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Instead of creating a parent row group from the detail group, I have to add a group expression to the detail group itself!

SSRS takes some getting used to - not the easiest to follow at first

Comment: Glad you got it sorted but there should be no need to add grouping to the details group. Normally you would start with the detail rows (the second part in your case) then add a parent group that groups by student and include a header.  In the header you can add additional rows or expand the row to put all the header data into. I'm just telling you this so you don't start on a path in SSRS which is much harder than it needs to be . SSRS for basic stuff like this is quick and easy (IMHO). I can post a short GIF showing it in action if that would be helpful.

Comment: sure that would be great Alan.  When I added the parent group, I couldn't get the report to preview in the format I needed.  When I add a parent group, it puts the group as first column and I needed to group on the whole rectangle comprised of studentname, dob, and email. So couldn't figure out how to do it that way

Comment: I'll add an answer to I can include the gif and explain a couple of things

Comment: Alan, Thanks man, appreciated it.  That's a great video.  What screen recorder did you use?

Comment: It's called ScreenToGif, it's great for embedding short videos in emails and places like SO, I think that gif is only 1.5Mb. And the best bit is it's free !